# Netty HTTP server and data compression proxy in mobile Chrome/Opera - some images not visible

Tags: http, proxy, netty

I wrote a small http server in java with Netty as core. Problem is that mobile browsers don't show some images, when data compression proxy is enabled (data saver in chrome, traffic economizer in opera)
On PC everything is ok, on mobile phone, connected to wi-fi (compression disabled) everything is ok also, but when mobile phone is working in gsm network (no wi-fi) some images are not visible. In opera (android version) the same - when compression is disabled all pictures are visible, when enabled - some are not visible.
Example: 
http://tdpol.ru/template/imgs/404.jpg <- this image is not visible
http://tdpol.ru/template/imgs/map-sm.jpg <- this image is visible
Both images are returned to clients in the same way, response is 200 (OK) headers are:

```
CONTENT_TYPE, "image/jpeg"
CONNECTION, HttpHeaderValues.CLOSE
CONTENT_LENGTH, response.content().readableBytes()
```

ChannelHandlerContext is written with retain, then closed and decoder is destroied:

```
ctx.writeAndFlush(response.retain());
ctx.close();
decoder.destroy();
```

What should i implement for compression proxies to operate normally? I tried setting 304 response code

Here are headers for failing picture with compression enabled (via gsm network):

```
Request header: Host: tdpol.ru
Request header: Connection: keep-alive
Request header: Cache-Control: max-age=0
Request header: Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Request header: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; ASUS_Z00AD    Build/LRX21V) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.98 Mobile Safari/537.36
Request header: Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Request header: Referer: http://tdpol.ru/ca2
Request header: Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Request header: Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Request header: Cookie: _ym_uid=1472566224516803345
Response header: content-type: image/jpeg
Response header: connection: close
Response header: content-length: 52249
```

And here are headers for the same picture with compression disabled (via wi-fi)

```
Request header: Host: tdpol.ru
Request header: Connection: keep-alive
Request header: Cache-Control: max-age=0
Request header: Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Request header: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; ASUS_Z00AD Build/LRX21V) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.98 Mobile Safari/537.36
Request header: Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Request header: Referer: http://tdpol.ru/ca2
Request header: Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Request header: Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Request header: Cookie: _ym_uid=1472566224516803345
Response header: content-type: image/jpeg
Response header: connection: close
Response header: content-length: 52249
//Here chrome requests also favicon.ico:
Request header: Host: tdpol.ru
Request header: Connection: keep-alive
Request header: Pragma: no-cache
Request header: Cache-Control: no-cache
Request header: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; ASUS_Z00AD Build/LRX21V) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.98 Mobile Safari/537.36
Request header: Accept: */*
Request header: Referer: http://tdpol.ru/template/imgs/404.jpg
Request header: Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Request header: Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Request header: Cookie: _ym_uid=1472566224516803345
Response header: content-type: image/ico
Response header: connection: close
Response header: content-length: 1150
```

as i can see, they are identical, the only difference - without compression chrome requests a favicon.ico file after getting image
No requests about cache validity (if file was modified) present in both cases so it's not a sync fault.

p.s. i've tried repacking image (original is saved with photoshop, tried paint in case proxy's resampler fails to manage it) and renaming it (in case proxy contains some erroneous sample of it in cache) - nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured out
Proxy is not the one to blame, it is just used on SLOWER (important) connections by default
Problem was in latency between writeAndFlush and close - on high speed direct connections 50kb file was flushed before actual forced channel close, on slower connections only part of file was transferred, so proxy was unable to compress it. Test with slow direct connection showed that only part of image was transferred.
Removing close and reset - fixed situation.
So Close must be implemented in ChannelFuture (or ChannelFuture's complete event listener)